# What is the idiomatic way of saying “he is ticklish under armpits”?

Tags: vocabulaire

Seems like an easy thing, but Google search rendered that:

- il est chatouilleux sous/sur (les) aisselles
- il a des chatouilles sous/sur (les) aisselles

and permutations (including different articles) are extremely rare, if present at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« il est chatouilleux sous les aisselles »

In French you can be *chatouilleux **sous** les aisselles*.

> [Depuis Darwin, qui avait observé que les chimpanzés sont aussi chatouilleux  sous les aisselles que les enfants, l'homme se demande s'il descend bien du singe et comment](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Q74LCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT113&lpg=PT113&dq=%22chatouilleux%20sous%20les%20aisselles%22&source=bl&ots=jdHLG7pQU3&sig=ACfU3U1-EZ_WqES0xGi--fuFjvccC9-Hzg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM7YeSlvbjAhXdDmMBHVqrDyoQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22chatouilleux%20sous%20les%20aisselles%22&f=false). (*Le Nouveau Totem: Petites chroniques du cerveau* de Patrick Davous)

> Pourquoi est-on chatouilleux sous les aisselles et sous la plante des pieds ? (*Les Problèmes*, Aristote ([?](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probl%C3%A8mes)) , Section XXXV, du toucher, § 3 i09)

But when tickling isn't involved it can be **sur** :

> [Les champignons dans l'aine et sur les aisselles](http://www.doctissimo.fr/sante/diaporamas/champignons-mycoses-peau/champignons-aine-aisselles).

> [Pulvérisez directement du jus de citron sur les aisselles,](https://cosmeto-nature.com/fr/blog/astuces-pour-s-eclaircir-les-aisselles--n3)

*Être chatouilleux sous les aisselles* can be used in a figurative way to mean one is touchy. It is very colloquial. An instance in [this forum](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?3,998019,998503) :

> Avec un pseudo comme bourbaki, tu ne devrais pas être aussi chatouilleux sous les aisselles. Les engueulades bourbachiques appartiennent à l'histoire me suis-je laissé dire.

Comment: I must just say that for such a basic concept, there is way too many (and somewhat uncertain) ways of addressing this :D

Answer (score 2):

I think *chatouiller sous les bras* is more common.

On further reflection, another way of saying this could be :

- Il/elle rigole quand on le/la chatouille sous les bras/les aisselles.

Comment: Tiens, intéressant, mais comment dire qu’une personne est susceptible d’être chaoutillée là-bas ?

Comment: Je dirais qu'elle est chatouilleuse sous les bras.

Answer (score 2):

Je vois 2 traductions qui peuvent convenir

> Il est chatouilleux sous les aisselles
>
> Il est chatouilleux des aisselles

Toutes les formes de "Il a des chatouilles..." ne fonctionnent pas, car au mieux on pourrait dire "Ça lui chatouille sous les aisselles", mais le sens est alors différent, car cela veut dire en gros "Ça lui démange sous les aisselles" (et encore je ne suis pas certain qu'employer chatouiller dans ce sens ne soit pas un belgicisme), et non pas "Il va réagir vivement si on le chatouille sous les aisselles".

Celle-ci est peut-être aussi correcte :

> Il est chatouilleux aux aisselles

mais me paraît moins idiomatique, j'attends les réactions des autres membres...

Comment: _Chatouilleux des..._, vraiment excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'utilise chatouilleux que seul donc :

> Il est chatouilleux.

mais :

> Il craint les chatouilles sous les bras.

Answer (score 2):

En plus des autres choix, je dirais (au Qc.), peut-être plus familièrement, comme on le propose ailleurs (*bras*) mais avec une locution prépositive :

> Il est chatouilleux en dessous des bras.

Même si techniquement la [*partie la plus basse*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=en%20dessous&id=3116) du bras, le revers du bras, voire la partie du corps sous les bras, n'est pas l'aisselle, on peut dire familièrement [*dessous-de-bras*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dessous-de-bras) pour *aisselle*, et je trouve cette phrase de prime abord imprécise tout à fait naturelle et sans équivoque. C'est probablement ce que je dirais spontanément à l'oral.